# Horizontally center one of three anchor tags

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have 3 links in a footer. They should be positioned left, center and right. The links on the side have some margin on the sides. How do I center the middle link? I can change my html to a UL if that is necessary.

This is my code so far:

```
<footer>
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <a href="#" class="link2">Link2</a>
        <a href="#" class="link3">Link3</a>
</footer>
```

---

```
footer {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.link2 {
  //This should be centered
}

.link3 {
  float: right;
}
```

Link to Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FgpAq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could text-align the footer to center and float the first and last links. I've used `.link1` and `.link3` but you could use `footer a:first-child` and `footer a:last-child` if you don't care that pseduo-classes are not supported by all browsers.

```
<footer>
    <a href="#" class="link1">Link1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link2">Link2</a>
    <a href="#" class="link3">Link3</a>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
  text-align:center;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.link1 {
  float:left;
}

.link3 {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas Already considered and rejected as pseudo classes do not work on all browsers.

Comment: Does `a:first` work? I wasn't aware that was a valid CSS selector; `:first-child` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer, providing you know in advance how many links there'll be:

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
}

footer a:first-child {
    float: left;
}

footer a:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bSKRK/1/).

This aligns all the links to the center of their parent element, and then moves the `:first-child` to the left, and the `:last-child` to the right.

Comment: There are no pseudo-elements in this example.

Answer (score 0):

A couple more options:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

footer a {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

.link2 {text-align: center; width: 34%;}
.link3 {text-align: right;}


</style>


</head>
<body>

<footer>
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <a href="#" class="link2">Link2</a>
        <a href="#" class="link3">Link3</a>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 20px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

footer a {
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
}

.link2 {text-align: center; width: 34%;}
.link3 {text-align: right;}


</style>


</head>
<body>

<footer>
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <a href="#" class="link2">Link2</a>
        <a href="#" class="link3">Link3</a>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though this may not be good practice you could just do this:

```
.link2 {
    margin-left: 800px;
}
```

Using this method will let you play freely with your link and move it however you wish.